# What would Saruman join forces with Sauron for?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, character-motivation

[Curumo (Saruman)](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Curumo) is not known, AFAIK, to have forgotten his identity and his mission from the Valar. Even ignoring his commitment to the Valar - he knows that [Mairon (Sauron)](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Mairon)'s master, Melkor, is gone; and that he won't be coming back; and that the most Mairon can do is basically provoke the Valar into slightly more intervention. Hell, even if Mairon has a stable "victory" - what's the use in that for Curumo? It's not as though Mairon can mount a challenge of the Valar.

So why would Curumo even consider joining forces with Mairon? What did he expect to achieve? If he thought the opposition to him by the Istari, Elves and Men was going to fail - shouldn't he have just gone back to Valinor, or barring that,  taken up a chair at the Gray Havens somewhere and watched it all crash and burn?

Comment: maybe worth providing the more commonly known names for these characters

Comment: Sauron wasn't awaiting Morgoth's return; he was doing what he was doing to for his own ends, and assumed (correctly) that the Valar were no longer interested in direct action against him in Middle Earth.

Comment: @NKCampbell: Ok, in the title. But the use of the original names is appropriate for my question. Plus, I don't buy into all of the anti-Mairon propaganda :-)

Comment: But Sauron hasn't been Mairon since he was taken under Melkor's wing, so calling him as such is pretty ridiculous... Furthermore Saruman is different Curumo... Same as Mithrandir is not Olorin

Comment: lol, I had almost put in my comment "...proper naming / timeline semantics aside" :D - just saying, a lot people would skip the question because they would have no idea what you're talking about

Comment: also..."Mairon" as a name for Sauron seems to be barely canon anyway

Comment: @Edlothiad: Sauron is just a derogatory term the Elves adopted. Mairon's the name. Or - did he change him name at some point?

Comment: @NKCampbell: Maiorn is the name for Mairon. Sauron is just a derogatory nickname. Anyway, you've changed my opinion back about the title.

Comment: I feel like using super obscure names in place of the common ones, particularly if it really is in support of an interpretation that "Saron did nothing wrong," significantly detracts from the question. It renders it incredibly confusing to anyone who has only read the main series and not ancillary material unpublished during Tolkien's lifetime.

Comment: Plus, as other people have mentioned, the Istari weren't entirely the same as their Maia counterparts. Further, both Sauron and the Istari had adopted these names and used them to refer to themselves. Gandalf frequently called himself Gandalf (while admitting he answers to other names). The Mouth of Sauron, the official spokesperson of Sauron, did not call him Mairon. Some of the Nazgul may have also done so. In Sauron's case, this is presumably because, in Tolkien's fashion, he had become sufficiently corrupted that he was proud of being abhorred rather than admired.

Comment: yup - downvoting now for being deliberately obtuse and pedantic rather than helpful to the majority of users :)

Comment: @NKCampbell: No, you've clarified to me that the issue is not really about "helpfulness", but rather about the view of who the characters are.

Comment: Come on. Even if you think Gandalf thinks of himself as Olorin, and Sauron as Mairon, and Saruman as Curumo (I doubt this, but I could see the argument), you've got to see that someone whose read the books or seen the movies could read your question, to say nothing of if they just see the title, and have literally no idea that it's about the Lord of the Rings, if they miss the tags. You didn't even put an explanation in parentheses (Mairon, better known as Sauron). It would be like asking a question about Erik Weisz without ever mentioning his stage name.

Comment: @Adamant: Hmmm. Fine, I'll be wishy-washy, bow to public pressure and change the title back.

Comment: For that matter, where is the name Mairon even published? I know I've seen it before, but I can't find it in the index of *The Silmarillion*, *Unfinished Tales*, or any volume of *The History of Middle Earth*. The only citation in the Wikipedia article for Sauron is issue 17 of *Parma Eldalamberon*, which I know I've never actually seen, and I don't know where *it* gets its information.

Comment: @chepner: There's at least this reference: J.R.R. Tolkien, "Words, Phrases and Passages in Various Tongues in The Lord of the Rings", in Parma Eldalamberon XVII (edited by Christopher Gilson), p. 183. (Found [here](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Sauron#cite_note-PE17.1-3)).

Comment: @einpoklum That's the citation I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: @chepner: Oh, sorry, yeah. I think I might have read it in the Encyclopedia of Arda by David Day. Otherwise I don't remember.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Saruman did not consider himself to have "joined forces" with Sauron. Rather, he no longer viewed him as an enemy, but rather a rival that need not be actively opposed, but cooperated with as needed. The goal was not to *help* Sauron, but to *delay* him until he could obtain the Ring for himself. That necessarily involved *not* being seen as part of the resistance against Sauron.

Sauron, on the other hand, likely viewed Saruman as a fool and someone to use. The parallel with Saruman's view of Radagast (as described in the essay on the Istari) is worth noting.

Comment: So, this quote: "A new power is rising. Against it the old allies and policies will not avail us at all. There is no hope left in Elves or dying Numenor. This then is one choice before you, before us. We may join with that Power. It would be wise, Gandalf. There is hope that way. Its victory is at hand; and there will be rich reward for those that aided it." - is a bluff?

Comment: Yes, as Gandalf immediately recognizes. "Saruman, I have heard speeches of this kind before, but only in the mouths of emissaries sent from Mordor to deceive the ignorant." Saruman then switches tactics and tries to tempt Gandalf with the idea of "sharing" the Ring to overthrow Sauron.